# <FIRESTORE> I can't get the combination of transaction and event processing to work

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, paypal

Thank you very much for your help.

I am currently implementing a function that registers data to the DB when payment is confirmed using Firebase's Firestore and PayPal.

When either the payment or the registration to the DB fails, one of the two is still being processed.

If the registration to the DB fails, the payment is also cancelled.
If the payment fails, cancel the registration to the DB.

If the payment fails, cancel the registration in the DB.
I thought it would be possible to use Firestore transactions in this situation, but
However, I don't know how to build them yet.

I've included the code for each below.
Buttons, when the payment is successful, the process in onApprove is executed, and when the payment fails, the process in onApprove is executed.
Buttons, when the payment is successful, the process in onApprove will be executed, and when the payment fails, the process in onError will be executed.

I'm trying to use Firestore transactions to do what I want to do.
Buttons in the transaction process, I don't think it will work because I don't want to catch errors in the .Buttons method itself.
Buttons method, it won't work because you don't want to catch errors in the processing of this .Buttons method itself. Also, for example, if you write a transaction process (in onApprove) after the payment is completed, it won't work because
I don't think you can cancel the payment since the payment has already been made.

I don't know how to achieve this as described above.
If you know how to do this, please let me know.

Firestore transaction documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?hl=ja#web-v8

````
// Create a reference to the SF doc.
var sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

// Uncomment to initialize the doc.
// sfDocRef.set({ population: 0 });

return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then((sfDoc) => {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }

        // Add one person to the city population.
        // Note: this could be done without a transaction
        // by updating the population using FieldValue.increment()
        Note: this could be done without a transaction // by updating the population using FieldValue.increment(). var newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
        transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
    });
}).then(() => {
    console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
});
```

PayPal's code
```
  <script
    function initPayPalButton() {
      paypal.Buttons({
        style: {
          shape: 'rect',
          color: 'gold',
          layout: 'vertical',
          label: 'paypal',
          
        },

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{"amount":{"currency_code": "JPY", "value":1}}]]
          });
        },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!') ;
          });
        },

        onError: function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    }
    initPayPalButton();
  </script>.
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you want to add a document in Firestore using transactions if the payment is approved by the user. The `onApprove` method *"captures the funds from the transaction and shows a message to the buyer to let them know the transaction is successful. The method is called after the buyer approves the transaction on paypal.com"*

> If you write a transaction process (in onApprove) after the payment is completed, it won't work because I don't think you can cancel the payment since the payment has already been made.

What do mean by this? The `onApprove` function will trigger only when the user approves the payment and then the Stripe SDK calls some [Orders API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create).

```js
onApprove: function(data, actions) {
  // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
  return actions.order.capture().then(async function(details) {
    // alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name + '!') 
    // This is where you run Firestore's transaction
    await addTxnToDatabase(details);
  }); 
},
```

Do you really need Firestore transactions? Are you updating something or just adding a new document in Firestore? If you are just adding a new doc then I guess transaction is not useful as *"Read operations must come before write operations in a Transaction"*. You can just simply write a new doc.

```js
async function addTxnToDatabase() {
  return firebase.firestore().collection("payments").add({..}) // any data returned by Paypal
}
```

In case you want to increment something, then you can use the increment method:

```
docRef.update({ field: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(50) })
```

Additionally, it might be useful to take a look at [Paypal Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/) which can trigger a Cloud function for you containing data of certain payment related events.

Comment: >If I'm not mistaken, you want to add a document in Firestore using transactions if the payment is approved by the user.
-> exactly.

My concern now is that if I simply insert the update or add method of the firestore in the onAprroved method after the payment, if that action(to firestore) fails, only the payment will be made and no update to the DB will be made.

Comment: @k_ele that's correct. I would try adding a [recursive function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion) which calls itself incase of failure. But I still prefer using cloud functions so if something fails, I can notify myself via an email or something. The Webhooks still remains the best option. I'm not sure about Paypal but Stripe retries every hour incase  of failure of processing webhook and notifies you if the issue persists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Recursion or using a webhook might be a better way to go!
I'll look into that direction, thank you very much!